# Only outputting plain text from TShark

Tags: sniffing, tshark

I was wondering if there was a feature like `follow TCP stream` for TShark.

I have a got a NetCat IRC server setup with the following command: `nc -lnvp 1234`.

My android phone connects with `netcat 10.0.0.1 1234`

In WireShark, if I type `tcp.port == 1234` in the display filter, it shows all the packets being sent between my computer and phone, and right-clicking then choosing `follow TCP stream` shows the plain text like this:

```
Hi
Hello!
How's it going?
Yeah good thanks
```

But I was wondering if I could get the same output from TShark.

Comment: "Follow TCP stream" doesn't limits the output to plain text at all. All it does is filter out any packet that doesn't belong a a specific TCP connection out of the capture and reorder the packets (if necessary).

Comment: The [tcpick](http://tcpick.sourceforge.net/) program does something similar.